# Ten times Thread.Sleep(100) or a single Thread.Sleep(1000)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a difference (from performance perspective) between:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Does the single call to `Thread.Sleep(10000)` also results in context switches within this 10 seconds (so the OS can see if it's done sleeping), or is this thread really not served for 10 seconds?

Comment: From a performance perspective, you shouldn't be calling Sleep at all. Event/interrupt driven models are much more performant.

Comment: From http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then_ **race your horses.**

Comment: A single `Thread.Sleep()` will really not serve the thread for 10 seconds.  I don't imagine that the OS would need a context switch to confirm that the thread is still sleeping; this would be handled outside of the thread.  From a performance perspective your question is meaningless, because the "performance" of a `Thread.Sleep` is entirely dependent on what other threads are running.

Comment: Short sleep-times allows to check for cancelation-conditions in the middle. This ofcause uses even more processor-cycles, but can allow for clean exists (even in programs with sleep), and you don't have to resort to stuff like `thread.Abort`.

Comment: @SonerGönül, The main thing i am interested in is "Does the single call to Thread.Sleep(10000) also results in context switches within this 10 seconds (so the OS can see if it's done sleeping), or is this thread really not served for 10 seconds?". But i don't know how to investigate that by just "Racing these two horses".

Comment: Others have stated some differences. I've one to add: one long sleep will be more accurate than multiple short sleeps.

Comment: @Jeroen1984 - the OS does not need to wake up the sleeping thread.  The sleeping thread gets 0 cycles during the sleep.  It's dead code for the duration.

Answer (score 2):

The second code (for loop) requires more process swaps and should be little slower than `Thread.Sleep(10000);`

Anyway you can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class to determine the exact time for these two approaches. I believe the difference will be very very small.

Comment: Indeed, the difference would only be noticeable if there were other threads running that actually did some processing between sleeps.

Answer (score 1):

in any case second loop will take time because of following overheads

1. Memory utilization for 10 different thread objects
2. 10 different callbacks will be initiated once you call thread.sleep
3. Overhead cost for running loop
4. if we want to run the code on single thread so why do we want a loop if we don't have any break point even.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But does anybody know if the OS does a context switch to the "Thread.Sleep(10000)"-thread within this 10 seconds, to see if the sleep is ready, or does it really not serve this thread for 10 seconds??

Comment: as per my knowledge OS set a callback event in memory and which interrupts CPU when the time is over and the CPU then processes the callback function, so the processor don't wait for this process to complete but it will process other threads.  This is how JS engine works too

Comment: To be pedantic, in OS terms the Sleep() call, (and other OS calls that can change thread states), is classed as an interrupt. The return from Sleep() is an interrupt-return.